# Prefer ellipsis or single template argument for overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, ellipsis

If you have a function that has a "preferred" implementation and another "fallback" implementation, something like the following

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<...>* = nullptr>
    void do_something_impl(T, some_tag) {}

    // fallback technique 1
    template <typename T>
    void do_something_impl(T, ...) {}

    // fallback technique 2
    template <typename T, typename Tag>
    void do_something_impl(T, Tag) {}
}
```

Is the preferred way to handle such a fallback 2 or 1?  I usually stick to 1 because that is the very last overload considered since the C++ compiler tries to avoid `...` as much as possible, but is there any other objective reason to avoid 1?

Comment: Passing a non-trivial object to #1 is implementation-defined and will very likely result in memory corruption (it was UB prior to C++11).

Comment: @ildjarn even if you end up never using that data type?

Comment: @ildjarn only for arguments that are potentially-evaluated. In these template-tricks scenarios, that's usually not the case.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : 'Usually' is usually fine, but the `typename Tag` approach is always fine. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn I don't see why it doesn't have to be always: since he is in complete control over how he calls `do_something_impl`, and actually also what he passes (`some_tag`), and he doesn't have to make the callside change dynamically at random or at other patterns to pass different objects of non-trivial objects, this approach will always be fine in the case `...` is applied. With the templated case aswell, if you try to pass something not convertible to `Tag`, a compiler error will be emitted aswell, therefore there will be a case where it's not "fine", under unclear callsite circumstances.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : I'll take a compiler error over potential memory corruption any day. As to a practical rationale, I once saw a codebase with a `std::string` inside of the tag hierarchy during debug builds; lots of fun was had tracing down the resulting stack corruption. The code was originally written correctly, and someone more naive came along later and added "helpful debugging features". Maybe I'm being overly dogmatic, but it's a fact that it wouldn't have been a problem if varargs were avoided.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : To put it another way, "*he is in complete control*" is more or less a fallacy in any real codebase, any you can't expect everyone to be perfect.

Comment: @ildjarn the one thing that I would want to add into this is that the case with the Tag method sometimes will do things like make a copy, etc that you don't want, whereas the ... is simpler because it accepts anything and is the last thing considered in any overload.  Further since its in the detail namespace nobody else will be making calls to it?

Comment: @ildjarn are you saying if i say `return 1.0;` I may not be returning `1.0` in any *real* codebase? This appears to be a strawmen. What I actually said that in this particular "provide a fallback for two functions that otherwise would be equal" case, there is complete control of what argument is passed. Of course there are cases in the real world for other issues where you are not in complete control. Those cases are not of concern here and I fail to see the connection.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : And that's fine. Isn't that why we're both commenting, and not answering? I'm not selling anything here.

Comment: @ildjarn Aren't you commenting because the question is primarily opinion-based? Asking for _a preferred way_ is usually a clue. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack : The way the question is phrased makes it sound subjective, but I think if there is an answer, it will be purely technically-based. Otherwise I would have close-voted straight away. ;-D

Comment: @ildjarn It's conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics, so implementations must either document the semantics and make it work, or emit a diagnostic.

Comment: One reason for `...` to be not a good choice is because there may be multiple fallbacks, one more catchy than the other. With tags, you can simply solve that with inheritance. With `...`, you can't solve that this way. BTW, your "fallback technique 2" won't work, because your "primary" alternative is a template aswell. It only works if the primary alternative is a non-template. Both being templates, there will be an ambiguity.